# Save List as Template from SharePoint 2007 Legacy Exception Site to 2010 Site Collection

Tags: site-collection, list-template

I'm having trouble getting a list with attachments associated with the items transferred to a new site collection. The biggest issue I'm having is access. No-one seems to know how to grant me the access I need or who would be in a position to do so.

Well, assuming that the access issue eventually gets sorted out I've been told that there may be an issue putting a List saved as a Template from a SharePoint 2007 Legacy Exception Site to a SharePoint 2010 New Site Collection.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Do you know if what I'm trying to do is possible? Slightly more challenging? No issue at all, follow typical steps?

Answer (score 1):

To move the list from 2007 to 2010, you have couple of choices.

Using save as tempalte:

1. Rename the original .STP to .CAB
2. Extract its manifest.xml to a local folder (lets call it
   {workingfolder})
3. Search for the ProductVersion element. This should have a value of 3
4. Change its value to 4
5. Repackage the manifest.xml into a .CAB. I've done this by using
   makecab.exe in the C:\Windows\System32 folder Syntax: makecab.exe
   {workingfolder}\manifest.xml {workingfolder}{template-name}.cab
6. Change the generated cabinet's extension from .CAB back to .STP and
   upload it into the _catalogs/lt

Read this blog for complete details: http://tom-dw.blogspot.com/2010/06/importing-sharepoint-2007-list.html

2nd Methos is use the 3rd party tools i.e ShareGate, Metalogix. they have trial version for 14 days, you can try it.

I am not sure what issue is your access to list. could you please give us more details what issue you faced...access denied or something else? what permission you have on the site collection?

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll definitely give this a shot if/when I get access.

The access issue occurs when I try to "Save list as template". The error is Access Denied. I clicked the "Request Access" link and about a day later a friend approached me saying that he received my request but didn't know how to grant me the access and didn't know why he received the request because he himself can't even access the list. I've since submitted a Remedy Request that yielded no results because they had no idea how to grant me access. I've also got my supervisor on the case but it's slow moving.

Comment: As far as 3rd party tools are concerned, that's probably not an option because we have to get permission to download pretty much anything and I don't have much time before my internship ends.

Comment: can that guy directly going to List setting > permission and give you full control or do same thing at Site collection level

Comment: I'm not sure, he doesn't seem to be in today. He definitely won't be able to do it at the List level because he can't access the list. Maybe at the site collection level but I won't find out today. When I go into the List settings I can see that I already have Full Control, I can actually give my self Contribute access as well but when I click on "Save list as template" I still get the error.

Comment: you need full control / site collection rights to perform save as template

Comment: Are there different levels of 'full control'? I am shown as having 'full control' in the list permissions.

Comment: full control on list is not enough to perform the save as template...you need full on higher level...i.e if list is under sub-site then sub-site level other wise site collection level

Comment: Alrighty, I'm now in contact with someone fairly high up the chain so hopefully I get it sorted out. I'll post the results here.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got into contact with someone who is the "go-to guy" for SharePoint issues around here and he gave me a very simple solution to bypass the access issue and says that even if I got the access and tried to save the list as a template it wouldn't work because of the size of the list.

So what he did was open MS Access and go to the "more" option in External Data. From there he selected "SharePoint List" and pasted the url of the existing list on the old site. He selected the "Import" radio button and clicked next. He then chose the same option but this time pasted in the url of the new site and selected "Link to the data source by creating a linked table" and clicked next.

I now have the list on the new site with the attachments in place. For anyone attempting to do the same thing I would suggest not messing around with saving the list as a template and simply use Access.

Now, I do like the answer provided. It does seem like a good solution but because I didn't use it, should I not vote it up?

Comment: Yes, if you found the answer useful, give it an upvote!

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I guess I don't have enough reputation to upvote lol.